# InfluxDB2.0 How to calculate daily value over bigger timeframe?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I'm migrating my InfluxDB1.8 version to InfluxDB2.0
I'm using a influxDB2.0 database and use grafana to display results.
What I insert as data are the results of my P1 meter, altough the results are total values, I would like to calculate and display the daily results.
What is being inserting is the current (gas usage) value. By calculating the difference of the begin and end of the day, I have my daily usage result.

I did find out a way to do this for 1 day. With the Spread function. But I don't get it working for a longer timeframe then 1 day.

[image: day result]

But now to display this on a daily usage on a longer timeframe. I didn't find the right option to get this working
Week results
[image: Weekresults]

Anyone an idea?

Query for 1 day:

````
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "Gas-usage")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> spread(column: "_value")```
````

Comment: Can you share your data (in csv)? I will try to help you.

Comment: Hi @Amerousful,
I didn't saw your comment directly under this post.
Here you can find an week of data which is in influxdb 2.0.
I hope your offer to have an look is still valid, as so far I didn't get it correctly working.

Link to .csv on Google Drive.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wKZJ77JGqjExCWUZ7V2s8FkmOjoqLQRX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I did some checks on the 1.8 one and what works there is:

```
SELECT spread("value") 
FROM "Gas-usage" 
WHERE $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time(1d) fill(null) tz('Europe/Berlin')
```

what is the equivalant of this query in influxdb 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try change your aggregate window, like this:

```
|> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: mean)
```

Comment: In combination with 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: mean)
  |> derivative(unit: 1d, nonNegative: true, columns: ["_value"], timeColumn: "_time")

Then it shows the values per day.
I only need to fix a timezone issue then. As the time starts at 02:00. Which seem utc +2.

Comment: Did you found a solution for the 02:00 problem?

Answer (score 0):

use the spread function inside your aggreagateWindow function.

should be like this:

```
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "Gas-usage")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
|> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: spread, createEmpty: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from(bucket: "${bucket}")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "system")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.host == "${host}")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "uptime")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: spread, createEmpty: false)
```

[`result of my grafana`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXrln.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are a genius. I'm new to SO so it's not letting me attach the image directly but the spread function was the only piece I was missing. The top chart in the pic was used to check manually whether the daily totals were correct.

EDIT: `increase()` is not what I wanted. I should have been using `cumulativeSum()`. Query below is edited to be correct.

```
from (bucket: "${buckets}")
  |> range(start: -7d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "Tstat")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["Location"] == "${site}")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "compHeat1" or r["_field"] == "auxHeat1" or r["_field"] == "compCool1")
  |> cumulativeSum(columns: ["_value"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: spread, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "spread")
```

[barchart i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NInPE.jpg)